# A word to refer to the user who has already logged in and is using the application?

Tags: single-word-requests, computing

Software engineers frequently refer to two types of website users. The user has been logged into the application and the ones that haven't.

As the logged-in users always have a session on the application, I considered choosing *sessioner*. However, most spell checkers mark it as a misspelled word.

Are there any better single-world alternatives, please?

Members and guests/visitors can be used to refer to logged-in users and not-logged-in users! But both have other types of connotations that make the less than ideal to purely refer to authenticated and not-authenticate users.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96307/discussion-on-question-by-phpst-a-single-word-to-refer-to-a-current-user).

Comment: [Choosing the name of a computer programming variable is out of scope for our site  according to our Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I added an example sentence as this is a single word request. Feel free to change as appropriate. @tchrist it's not necessarily a variable. It can also be used in regular conversation. For example, if we are speaking you would be the interlocutor. If you are logged into our application, what would I call you? That's the question. ;)

Comment: @JJJ, in the now-deleted comments, the OP made it clear that the term will 'just be used for programming'.

Comment: @jsw29 be that as it may, answers are not just to help the OP but also others (and more importantly even, as there are many more others than just the asker) who are looking for such a word.

Comment: I don’t understand the situation. Your use of the definite article implies that only one person can be logged in at a time. This seems strange in real world terms. This is not just nit picking because it affects what type of word will work. Can you confirm that your system is not multi-user, please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [choosing the name of computer programming variables is out of scope for our site  according to our Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @tchrist, you comment is strange. When people are after a word we should help them regardless of its usage. When we need a word it may be for our academic paper, for an advertisement and for any other purpose. The answer of this question will appear in numerous documentations and it will be used in everyday conversations among developers. Why do you degrad the word needs of IT people?

Comment: @PHPst Picking good names for things is notoriously hard and undeniably important, be they for your business or product, your child or pet, or your program, object class, or variable. But neither being hard nor important makes requests for help in naming things a good fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A model. It is not actually a question about how to solve a particular problem you are having, but a request for a personal recommendation. It is completely subjective with no objective criteria possible for choosing a right answer over a wrong one. It is unlikely ever to help future visitors here.

Comment: @tchrist thanks for your comment. Word choice is an integral part of language study. If we cannot talk about here, where can be? What is the harm of having this questions here? According to which evidence you are predicting that it will not help others? Even in this page we see people that have interest in this subject. Restricting what people can ask here just leads to a less active and hibernated application.

Comment: @PHPst Perhaps you should ask this on an actual programming site then. We have many, of which [softwareengineering.se] and [ux.se] are just two.

Comment: @tchrist, the answer of this question obviously need English knowledge and not technical proficiency.

Comment: Please feel free to raise these issues on our site meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a different exchange that seems to conclude that there is no good single word. Some suggest **Member**.

> https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/95088/whats-a-good-single-word-term-that-means-a-user-whos-signed-in-to-your-websit

Other possibilities:

If you are looking for a word to describe recent (but *not necessarily current*) users I'd suggest **returner** as it implies that they are likely to be back. (This is how I think of active users. They generally interact with the product, but might not be currently on). Also, **constituent** might work depending on your context. Constituent is normally used for a voter in an election, but does imply occasional interaction and is most likely not used for anything else on your application.

For specifically people who are logged on at *this moment in time* I might suggest **submitter**. However, this would seem to also include anyone that has submitted a request even if they have now logged off (for example a bug report might have a submitter that is not current). Another option is **actor**. Actors are be definition doing some action (outside of movie/play context) and therefore is a decent word for the currently active users.

If you just want unique words that are marginally related, what about **bustler** or **hustler**. They both share the same formal definition according to Webster, but the second has a bad connotation so the first is a better option. Both imply activity which is related to currently logged on. You could even use a more out there word such as **adventurer** and just have a local comment giving it meaning.

Overall, I believe **Constituent** and **Actor** are the best two options I could come up with.

Comment: +1 for actor. I think that might be the best option for OP.

Comment: I really like the "actor", it is also compatible with "actor" in use-case diagram.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_(UML)

Comment: I intended to mark your answer for the bounty, sadly the question is put on hold.

Answer (score 2):

[Active users](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_users) are those who have used a given online service during a specific period of time (e.g., for the last month), whereas current users are those who are currently logged in.

As far as I know, there's no single word for a "currently logged in user" that is idiomatically used in the industry. A "current user" is as far as you can shorten it. So if you're simply using it for the internal labeling, I suggest you use the word 'current' or 'logged-in', because the 'user' label is always redundant in your situation.

Comment: If a time period isn't specified I believe that 'active user(s)' would be interpreted as 'users currently interacting with the system' and would be just as valid as 'current  users'. This meaning should also be reasonably clear from the broader context of any statements in which it is used.

As a web designer, I'd suggest 'active user(s)' is less vulnerable to misinterpretation than any of the other suggestions (including my own) and I think this outweighs any perceived benefits of a single word term.

Also, it is a natural fit for the 'blank' in the example provided by the OP.

Comment: *Current* and *active* are both ambiguous in the same way: they can mean that one is logged in, or merely that one has recently been logged in with reasonable frequency. If one wishes to use either of them unambiguously, one has to explicitly disambiguate it. Alternatively, one can just use *logged-in*, which is not ambiguous in that way.

Answer (score 1):

'Operant' is a good fit; the current operator of the application or website. This is a less specific equivalent to the driver of car, pilot of a plane etc, which are by definition the 'current user' of these devices.

From https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/operant and also https://www.dictionary.com/browse/operant

> An operative person or thing

References per the request from @shoover.

Comment: Here at EL&U, we're looking for high-quality answers with references, not based on "I think" or "It feels." Please [edit] your answer to provide some citations for this usage.

Comment: Answer updated as requested.

Comment: 'operant' is another really good candidate after 'actor'. an issue is spell checkers which mark it as a typo.

Comment: ‘Operator’ and ‘operative’ are also worth considering; I prefer the latter. You would need to ensure this was recognised as a noun, rather than an adjective meaning ‘functional’ - see https://www.dictionary.com/browse/operative, but this should be clear from the context. Might also address your spell-check issue.

Answer (score 1):

We ussually refer to such users as **visitors**. It says that this user is currently looking at web page and it is active. It only refers to users for the amount of time when he or she is clicking on web page / app.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the word **online** for the words *currently logged in*.

For instance : Frequently developers need to refer to the user who is [online/currently logged in] on the application.

For reference, take this excerpt from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_and_offline#Offline_messages) (especially the last sentence):

> With the growing communication tools and media, the words offline and online are used very frequently. If a person is active over a messaging tool and is able to accept the messages it is termed as online message and if the person is not available and the message is left to view when the person is back, it is termed as offline message. In the same context, the person's availability is termed as online and non-availability is termed as offline.